# Объединение запросов MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Написал простой почтовый модуль для сайта. В таблице хранятся письма, где есть таке поля как получатель, статус прочтения, папка которой принадлежит письмо.
Юзер кликает на нужную папку с письмами и получает список:

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `idreciver` = "<получатель>" AND `folder` = <нужная папка>
```

Но мне нужно в общей среде с папками показать пользователю сколько писем лежит в каждой папке.  (Например: Входящие (15), Исходящие (25), Архивные (10).

Я делаю 3 запроса с просчётом строк и помещаю данные в нужные поля:

```
$писем в папке № 1 = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `message` WHERE `idreciver` = "<получатель>" AND `folder` = <папка №1>

$писем в папке № 2 = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `message` WHERE `idreciver` = "<получатель>" AND `folder` = <папка №2>

$писем в папке № 3 = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `message` WHERE `idreciver` = "<получатель>" AND `folder` = <папка №3>
```

Я уже понимаю что это бред, а если папок 100? Но проблема усугубляется, когда мне нужно посчитать сколько в каждой из папок не прочтённых писем.

У каждой строки есть поля "readed" со статусом прочтения. И что бы мне вывести пользователю не просто количество писем по папкам но и сколько из них писем прочтённые а сколько не прочтённые, мне что, нужно сделать ещё 6 запросов для 3 папок? Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Так сделай один запрос, просто добавив GROUP BY FOLDER

Comment: Да, это отгруппирует по папкам, а как насчет доп.столбца прочитано / непрочитано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте `group by` для каждой папки, тем самым получите для каждой папки общее количество сообщений и отдельно сделать разбивку на прочтенные и непрочтенные:

```
SELECT `folder`,
    COUNT(*) as all_messages, /* Все сообщения в папке */
    sum(`readed`) as readed_messages, /* Только прочтенные сообщения */
    sum(if(`readed` = 0, 1, 0)) as unread_messages /* Только непрочтенные сообщения */
FROM `message` 
WHERE `idreciver` = "<получатель>" 
group by `folder`
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a600a/1/0).

Comment: Спасибо тебе запечательный программер уровня БОГ :)

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии не забывайте отмечать ответ как правильный галкой напротив)